# Explorer doesn't recognize HDD

Tags: drivers, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive

Windows explorer doesn't see my USB external HDD, and I can't see it in disk management. The software of the manufacturer can see it, and says it's completely working.

I tried to uninstall the device, from device management. I plugged it into another PC (Windows 7) and explorer doesn't see it either. I tried to uninstall the drivers with the command prompt, but that didn't work.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the program.]

[image: Here you can see disk management]

And here you can see device manager:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGj3s.png]

I use windows 10.

Comment: open disk management and assign a drive letter: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-add-remove-drive-letter#1TC=windows-7

Comment: It's not visible in disk managment.

Comment: post more pictures from device manager, disk managment

Comment: Added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment answering to ask for more information.

Does the BIOS recognize it before you've booted into windows? If not then there's nothing you can do for the drive. If you can see it try using a linux distro (Anything that supports live,) to reformat the drive before booting into windows.

Comment: The BIOS sees the drive, and so does the programme installed on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear about your issues with the WD Elements desktop drive, @mathijs! :( I'd advise you to try rescanning for disks through Disk Management and see if that will help the drive pop up.

According to the SMART results from the Data LifeGuard Diagnostics tool, the drive should be perfectly healthy.

Another thing you could try is using a third-party data recovery tools at your own risk to check if they will detect the drive properly. The other alternative that comes to mind is using [Ubuntu Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) to try to access the external HDD.

If you have any important data stored there that is not backed up, I'd strongly recommend you to consider contacting a professional data recovery company. You can also check some of [WD's worldwide Data Recovery Partners](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=b6lKy0).

Hope this helps. Keep us posted & Good luck!

Comment: I used this drive the backup my data from the MyBook hdd which failed last week. I'm going to try the ubunta live cd.